# SequenceEqual does not work below in comparing class

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to compare the following data below. How come SequenceEqual does not work below? I created two list classes, and want to compare.

```
        public partial class Product
        {
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        }

        List<Product> product1 = new List<Product>();
        List<Product> product2 = new List<Product>();

        product1.Add(new Product
        {
            ProductId = 1,
            ProductName = "TV",
            ProductDescription = "Television Set"
        });

        product2.Add(new Product
        {
            ProductId = 1,
            ProductName = "TV",
            ProductDescription = "Television Set"
        });


        if (product1.SequenceEqual(product2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("equal data");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not equal data");
        }
```

Comment: Without an [equality comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7.2) (third example down), your code is just comparing the references, which are different since they are two different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SequenceEqual` compares the two sequences to see if the contain the same objects. In your case they don't. They contain different `Product` references.

If you change your code to use the same `Product` in each list then `SequenceEqual` will return `true'

```
var product = new Product
{
    ProductId = 1,
    ProductName = "TV",
    ProductDescription = "Television Set"
};

product1.Add(p);
product2.Add(p);


if (product1.SequenceEqual(product2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("equal data");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not equal data");
}
```

Why? Because in this example the lists contain the same object.

[Read this](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-equality-operator) for more information on how `SequenceEqual` compares the two sequences.

If you want `SequenceEqual` to return true if the properties of the `Product` class are the same then you need to override the `Equals` method on the `Product` class.

**EDIT**

As others have mentioned, it is a better practice to implement the [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface instead of directly overriding the `Equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `SequenceEqual` method compares elements in the collection using the default comparer, which does a reference comparison — See [the official documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__), especially the *Examples* section.

If you want to compare the data of the objects rather than the references, you have two options (that I took from the page linked above):

- have the `Product` class implement the `IEquatable<Product>` interface; or
- create a separate class that implements the `IEqualityComparer<Product>` interface and use the overload of `SequenceEqual` that takes an instance of `IEqualityComparer<T>`

I suggest that you read the documentation page for more detailed information and examples on how to implement these two options.